# Add Custom Menu Item To Excels Quick Access Toolbar

Tags: vba, excel, toolbar, excel-2013

Is it possible using Excel 2013 to add a "button" or a shortcut to the Quick Access Toolbar that when clicked will take you to the 1st worksheet in the workbook?

I know that you can use a macro of `Sheets(1).Select` but how can this be done via a button from the Quick Launch - that would work for any user opening the workbook, not just the creators credentials?

Comment: Why not just [create a macro, and put it on the QAT](http://www.dummies.com/software/microsoft-office/excel/how-to-assign-macros-to-the-ribbon-and-the-quick-access-toolbar-in-excel-2013/)?

Comment: @BruceWayne - it is my understanding (and please forgive me if I am incorrect) that the QAT is user specific.  I need this to work for multiple users.

Comment: By "multiple users", do you mean they're each using their own Excel on separate computers?  Ah, in that case yes. I just thought you may have multiple people accessing the same version of Excel.

Comment: Yes - each opening on a different computer.

Answer (score 0):

1- write the folowing macro in module 1

```
' Code module Module1
Sub GotoSheet1()
    Sheets(1).Activate
End Sub
```

Then from the menu:

```
Customize Quick-Access-Toolbar --> more commands -->
choose commands from --> macros --> select the macro GotoSheet1.
```

Done, you have your button!

Comment: Is there a way to do the Customize Quick-Access-Toolbar steps from within the VBA syntax?  Or would it work better if I created a "template" workbook that already has the code and button generated, and open that each time to write data to it?

Comment: @YohanGreenburg There must be a way, more complicated and time consuming but feasible. The idea of a template looks good for me.